# What is the divergence of a uniform field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, gauss-law

I was recently studying Maxwell's equations. Got a bit confused about divergence. Would someone please tell me if the divergence of a uniform electric field = $0$, & why it is so?

Answer (score 2):

The divergence of a field talks about the existence of 'source/sink charges' for it at a given point. A field is locally directed towards (converges) a sink, and away from a source (diverges). The divergence is non zero at a point where a source or sink exists. Conventionally, positive charges are sources, and negative ones are sinks.

A uniform field has zero divergence because it cannot possibly have source or sink charges. (i.e it doesn't diverge/converge locally from/towards a point.)

A field with non zero divergence: (notice how it diverges from a certain point)

[image]

A uniform field: (notice how it doesn't seem to *arise* from a certain point)

[image]

(Mathematically, what is the divergence of ($E_x , E_y , E_z)$, if all those components are constants?)

Answer (score 0):

Divergence can be defined as an ratio of "field flux out of a closed surface" and "volume of that closed surface", and let volume sink to zero, $dv \rightarrow 0$.

$$
 \text{div}\vec{E}=\frac{1}{dv}
\oint\vec{E}\cdot {d\vec{a}}
$$

Electric field flux out of a closed surface of a uniform field is always zero - how much in, how much out. (assuming by uniform field you mean things like $\vec{E}=3\hat{i}$)
So naturally the ratio of electric field flux and volume goes to zero. In other words, uniform field flux out of a closed surface is independent of volume chosen.